# XUnit and AutoFixture Exception No Data found for (test name)

Tags: unit-testing, xunit.net, autofixture

I have a very simple test as shown below. 
I try to freeze my two dependencies using the `AutoDataAttribute` + `AutoMoqCustomization`.

```cs
class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoMoqDataAttribute()
        : base(new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization()))
    { }
}

public class PrBatchEndorseBrokerTest
{
    [Theory, AutoMoqData]
    public void Process_ValidContext_CallsK2Workflows(
        [Frozen]Mock<IK2Datasource> k2,
        [Frozen]Mock<IAppConfiguration> config,
        PrBatchEndorseBroker sut)
    {
        // Arrange
        var data = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["Workflow"] = @"KLPurchaseRequest\PR",
            ["Activity"] = "Endorser",
            ["ViewFormURL"] = "/Form/KLPurchaseRequestApproval.Form",
            ["PositiveOutcome"] = "Endorse",
            ["NegativeOutcome"] = "Reject"
        };

        // Act
        sut.Process();

        // Assert
        k2.Verify(x =>
            x.StartInstance(It.IsAny<string>(),
                            It.Is<Dictionary<string, object>>(d =>
                                data.Keys.All(k => d[k] == data[k])))
            , Times.Once());
    }
}
```

For some reasons, when i run this test, i'm getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No data found for BlackBox.Stakhanov.Broker.Test.PrBatchEndorseBrokerTest.Process_ValidContext_CallsK2Workflows

I tried many things and i can't make it work! I think i'm missing something big and probably obvious!

Packages I'm using:

```
<package id="AutoFixture" version="3.47.8" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="AutoFixture.AutoMoq" version="3.47.8" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="AutoFixture.Xunit" version="3.47.8" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Castle.Core" version="3.3.3" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Moq" version="4.5.10" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="xunit" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="xunit.abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="xunit.assert" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="xunit.core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="xunit.extensibility.core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="xunit.extensibility.execution" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="xunit.extensions" version="1.9.0.1566" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Comment: Have you tried making `AutoMoqDataAttribute` `public`?

Comment: Yes same result. I tried to remove PrBatchEndorseBroker, add it back.. Always the same error

Comment: Could you please list _exactly_ which NuGet packages you're using? You can easily get a list with `Get-Package` from the NuGet Package Manager Console.

Comment: I have added packages

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When using xUnit.net 2, you should use [AutoFixture.Xunit2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Xunit2), not [AutoFixture.Xunit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Xunit).

You'll notice in your package list that you have `xunit.extensions` version 1.9.0.1566, which isn't compatible with xUnit.net 2.